# WiX XmlFile setValue on multiple lines

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I'm using the tag `<util:XmlFile>` with setValue to update the content of a xml file during instalation but it only replaces the first entry found.

As far I as googled, the design only updates the first one.

Has anyone faced this trouble?
Any other goood way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

You must use `bulkSetValue` instead of `setValue`.
More info: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_xmlfile.htm

Answer (score -1):

The workaround I've done is create a `CustomAction`. There it is easy with .NET using XmlDocument to read all nodes and replace all the values you need. I didn't like this option, but I think I had no other choice.