# WiX XmlConfig change values on multiple lines?

Tags: wix

Related: [WiX XmlFile setValue on multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210443/wix-xmlfile-setvalue-on-multiple-lines)

I'd like to update attributes on multiple xml nodes with one statement using XmlConfig. Is there an equivalent to XmlFile - bulkSetValue ?

This will update the first instance.

```
<util:XmlConfig Id="ServerWCFCertClientSettings" File="[#APP_CONFIG]" On="install" PreserveModifiedDate="yes" 
    Action="create"
    Node="value" 
    ElementPath="//configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint/identity/certificateReference" 
    Name="findValue"
    Value="[SELECTED_WCF_CERTIFICATE]" 
    Sequence="200" />
```

I could use XmlFile for this, but we're trying to standardize on XmlConfig for all operations.

Answer (score 0):

@Doug Though it's a more than a year old post but just in case this helps someone: [Setting a value XmlConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482610/setting-a-value-xmlconfig)